# Search bar positioning across dashboard?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, user-research, usability-testing, users

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsTXcW.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I have global search on top and there is local search i.e local to that page. So, what is the good practice to place local search? Does it have to remain at one particular position across all views or position can change as per use case of the views?

Comment: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/20620/two-search-bars-on-the-same-page-or-combination Check this out!!

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is **do not to use two search boxes**. Some sites like Youtube use them and it feels confusing to find where is the local one, as it appears in certain pages (like channels).

Github, on the other hand, uses the same search box for both searches:

[image]

[image]

But in any case, **display elements always in the same place across different pages, so the user knows where to find them without thinking**.

Comment: "do not use two search boxes" - it's as simple as that. Use "Results from this page" if needed as a filter or section title

Answer (score 0):

A common trend I see is for the global search bar to be at the top right corner, take Stack Exchange for example.

Though normally I would say group common functionality, since both the local and global search do the same thing essentially but with differing scopes, grouping them can cause some confusion. So my suggestion would be to have the global search bar at the top right, and the local placed centered or to the left of the page. This distancing of space helps separate them, and help establish their presumed functionality.

Labeling is your best friend here. The placeholder text can help the user better identify the scope in which the search is being applied. So instead of just saying "Search...", say "Find Customer", or "Search Q&A".

Answer (score 0):

One other way of repurposing the search to target an area:

[image: This page only search]